# Is there a way to prevent automatic variable from deletion?

Tags: c++, scope

I know it is the **really bad thing** to even think about and just for the record: I'm not trying to use it in any serious application, so please try to answer the question instead of pointing out how inappropriate it is.

---

Example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
class Example {
public:
    Example() {
        std::cout << "constructor called" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Example() {
        std::cout << "destructor called" << std::endl;
    }

    // some operator delete magic perhaps?
};

int main() {
    Example* example_pointer;

    {
        Example example; // prints "constructor called"
        example_pointer = &example;
    } // example still exists here, nothing is printed

    delete example_pointer; // deleting automatic variable manually
    // Prints "destructor called"

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: The only requirement is that main function should not change.

I realize that some things are simply not possible, so I won't cry if that's the case here. This question came to my mind only out of curiosity.

Comment: The simplest answer I can think about is change example object to static, which doesn't satisfy your third condition.

Comment: Just a note:  you've now edited to change the requirements (made the only requirement being that `main()` doesn't change, whereas before you also had requirements to not use operator `new` or smart pointers).    You're obviously hoping for some hack involving overloading `Example`s operators.    Overloading operators like `operator&()` and `operator delete()` does not provide any way to change the effect of scope on object lifetime.

Comment: @Peter yup, that's because I wrote not to use smarts / new in main first, later added third requirement and at the end I've realized that it might be misleading (:

Comment: auto variables don't get **deleted**; they get **destroyed**.

Comment: @PeteBecker the difference is subtle, both mean "to make memory where the object is accessible for reuse" though and no matter which term you use, everyone will know what you mean. Anyway, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: No, the difference is not subtle. An object is destroyed by running its destructor. That does not release the memory that the object occupied. An object is deleted by `operator delete`, which destroys it **and** releases memory that was allocated for it on the free store. You can only delete an object that was created with `operator new`. If you treat those terms as interchangeable you're missing the essential difference between scoped lifetimes and unbounded lifetimes, and your code will be slow and prone to memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try this at home but you could probably achieve something like this using a reference counted PIMPL and an overloaded `operator&`:

```
class ExampleImpl {
public:
    ExampleImpl() {
        std::cout << "constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    ~ExampleImpl() {
        std::cout << "destructor called" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Example {
    std::shared_ptr<ExampleImpl> impl;
public:
    Example() : impl(std::make_shared<ExampleImpl>()){}
    Example* operator&() { return new Example(*this); }
};
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/lmtYXh).

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it does exactly what I have asked for without breaking anything else. Also, kudos for using the `PIMPL` idiom!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but it's just not possible. As soon as the object on the stack goes out of scope your pointer will be invalid.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe there is some kind of hack (that could be inserted into  overloaded `operator&`) that would allow moving the object to the bottom of the stack, so it will be deleted last just before the end of `main`.

Comment: @Jezor you need to allocate stack in main() then and put something you want into what you allocate there.

Comment: @user1095108 that's against the rules! (;

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are using the wrong syntax to explicitly call an destructor (`delete` both calls the destructor and deallocates the memory storing the object); you want:

```
int main() {
    Example* example_pointer;

    {
        Example example; // prints "constructor called"
        example_pointer = &example;
    } // example still exists here, nothing is printed

    example_pointer->~Example(); // deleting automatic variable manually
    // Prints "destructor called"
}
```

That said, what you want is not possible. When an automatic variable goes out of scope, it will always be destroyed. The closest you could get would be to manually construct the `Example` object in stack memory that had been allocated earlier in main:

```
int main() {
    alignas(Example) char example_storage[sizeof (Example)];
    Example* example_pointer;

    {
        Example &example = *new (&example_storage) Example; // prints "constructor called"
        example_pointer = &example;
    } //nothing is printed; `example` is only a reference,
      //so when it goes out of scope no destruction happens

    example_pointer->~Example(); // deleting automatic variable manually
                                 // Prints "destructor called"
}
```

Comment: That seems like a yet another way of saying `new` and I don't think that custom stack is necessary. Also, it changes `main` function dramatically. Upvote for use of `alignas` though!

Answer (score 1):

The closest way would be to use a technique that explicitly disrespects scope.   There is one well-known way in C++ to make a change that disrespects scope, and that is to use the preprocessor.

A simple

```
#define Example static Example
```

after the class definition and before `main()` would have the required effect.

The only limitation is that the `delete example_pointer` would have undefined behaviour, and that the destructor would probably be invoked after `main()` returns (not before the `return` statement in `main()`).

Technically, this does actually change the `main()` function, since it alters the code seen in phases of compilation post preprocessing.

If you remove the `delete example_pointer`, all requirements except the last are met.

Comment: If you're resorting to this sort of insanity, you could also do `#define delete` to make the `delete` statement turn into a no-op.

Comment: `#define` to redefine any language keyword also causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter it's so evil, I like it. :D

Answer (score 1):

One way not contemplated by anyone yet is jmping out of the function instead of returning. That is, using inline assembly,intrinsics or longjmp(). This way the stack pointer won't be updated, destructors won't be called and the stack will remain unchanged.

### Example:

```
#include <csetjmp>

#include <iostream>

jmp_buf buf;

int const* p;

[[noreturn]] void f() noexcept
{
  int const a(666);

  p = &a;

  longjmp(buf, 1);
}

int main()
{
  if (setjmp(buf))
  {
    auto const t(*p);

    ::std::cout << t << ::std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    f();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and add an example? I would really appreciate it!